# Python extract unique values from CSV

Tags: python

I am using the following python script to remove duplicates from a CSV file

```
with open('test.csv','r') as in_file, open('final.csv','w') as out_file:
    seen = set() # set for fast O(1) amortized lookup
    for line in in_file:
        if line in seen: continue # skip duplicate

        seen.add(line)
        out_file.write(line)
```

I am trying to modify it so that instead of outputting the list without duplicates to final.csv it outputs the unique values that were found.

Kind of the opposite to what it does now.  Anyone got an example?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. "The list without duplicates" and "the unique values found" are the *same thing*.

Comment: By unique values, do you mean only one instance of the value being found?

Comment: No they're not, he means the list of the ones that are not duplicated, i.e they only exist once in the original file

Comment: @Tom That is not how I would read that phrase. At a bare minimum, it is *exceptionally* unclear and imprecise, and that wouldn't be "the opposite" of "what it does now."

Comment: @jpmc26 Tom's guess about OP _real_ problem is reasonable in light of the title the OP assigned to their question.

Comment: @gboffi Whether it's a reasonable guess or not is irrelevant. The question isn't clear, and we shouldn't guess at what the OP could mean. We should wait until they clarify. And the title doesn't offer any additional clues over the text; it's literally the same phrase.

Comment: @jpmc26 I think that the title tells the whole story but I may be wrong. We agree that the body of the Q is awfully written.

Comment: Ok lets take a simple list of number [1,1,2,3], now give me the unique numbers in that list? are you going to give me [1,2,3] or [2,3]?

Comment: @Tom I would give you `[1,2,3]`. "Unique values" being a term without a defined technical meaning, I treat it as a synonym of "distinct values." That means "remove duplicates," not, "the values that only appear exactly once."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a dict to keep track of how many times each line occurs, then you can process the dict and add only the unique items to the `seen` set, and write those to the `final.csv`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
uniques = defaultdict(int)
with open('test.csv','r') as in_file, open('final.csv','w') as out_file:
    seen = set() # set for fast O(1) amortized lookup
    for line in in_file:
        uniques[line] +=1
    for k, v in uniques.iteritems():
        if v = 1:
            seen.add(k)
            out_file.write(k)
```

Or:

```
from collections import defaultdict
uniques = defaultdict(int)
with open('test.csv','r') as in_file, open('final.csv','w') as out_file:
    seen = set() # set for fast O(1) amortized lookup
    for line in in_file:
        uniques[line] +=1

    seen = set(k for k in uniques if uniques[k] == 1)
    for itm in seen:
        out_file.write(itm)
```

Or, using `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('test.csv','r') as in_file, open('final.csv','w') as out_file:
    seen = set() # set for fast O(1) amortized lookup
    lines = Counter(file.readlines())
    seen = set(k for k in lines if lines[k] == 1)
    for itm in seen:
        out_file.write(itm)
```

This will output **only** the lines which appear once, depending on what you mean by "uniques", this may or may not be correct. If, instead, you want to output ALL lines but only one instance per line, using the last method:

```
with open('test.csv','r') as in_file, open('final.csv','w') as out_file:

    lines = Counter(file.readlines())

    for itm in lines:
        out_file.write(itm)
```

Comment: For not using a `defaultdict`

Comment: A [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) would be appropriate here. There is no need to manage a dictionary of counts manually.

Comment: @gboffi revised to use defaultdict.

Comment: I don't like `defaultdict`

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the dublicates to another variable and use those to remove not unique values from the set.